# How to use the MSDeploy command for a destination website name with a hyphen?

Tags: web-deployment, msdeploy

I have a website named "something - somethingelse.com" in IIS. I want to use the MSDeploy command to deploy a package to this IIS site, but because I have a hyphen in my site name, it throws an error and expecting parameters after "-".

Is there any workaround other that rename the website in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the metakey instead of the AppHostConfig.

Example : source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1

You can find the number for your website (i.e. 1 in this example) from ID of your website. 
(on server type in "inetmgr" in start menu search -> Sites)